# Convert Days in Year, Month, Day datetime format

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

i studying TDateTime functions and procedure, but not found something that allow me to convert a number of days in equivalent Year, Month, Day, for example, if i have days = 0 i should to have as result:

```
Year:   0
Month:  0
Day:    0
```

or i have days = 1, should have:

```
Year:   0
Month:  0
Day:    1   // Just 1 day
```

or if i have days = 32:

```
Year:   0
Month:  1  // January is 31 days
Day:    1  // Day is 1 
           // Total are 32 days
```

etc, considering too when february month is of 29 days and not only 28. 
In delphi xe2, who can tell me what function do it, or if need write it manually? Thanks very much.

Comment: You should ask your question about tags on http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: There are several possibly intepretations of your question.

Comment: Thanks, solved about filter :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the methods in DateUtils:

```
procedure daysToDate(days: Integer; out day, month, year: Integer);
var
  january1st: TDateTime;
  targetDate: TDateTime;
begin
  january1st := StartOfTheYear(Now());
  targetDate := IncDay(january1st, days);

  day := DayOfTheMonth(targetDate) - 1;
  month := MonthOfTheYear(targetDate) - 1;
  year := YearOf(targetDate) - YearOf(january1st);
end;
```

This code assumes that you are counting the days in the current year. If you want to start in a different year then modify the line `january1st := StartOfTheYear(Now());` as needed.

Comment: @Marcello: If so, the intended interpretation of your question differs from the most natural one....

Comment: No, it solved about counter. In real, i wanted convert a integer (that represent miliseconds) in datetime format equivalent that turn me: years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds and miliseconds. I have tried with encodetime and it work well for hours, minutes, seconds and miliseconds but with encodedate not work. For example, in one days there are 86400000 miliseconds then i was sure that encodedate turn me 1 about days but it turn wrong values.

Comment: @Marcello: You could simply use `TimeStampToDateTime(MSecsToTimeStamp(MSecs))` where `MSecs` is the number of milliseconds. It won't work with the Encode* functions because they take words as parameter - and 86400000 causes an overflow.

Comment: @Chris, hello. I have tried with it, but i saw that return this exception. For example if i set MSecs to 999, i have this exception: EConvertError: '0.999' is not a valid timestamp; in this case as i can solve this exception?

Comment: @Marcello: You are right - `MSecsToTimeStamp` returns an invalid `TTimeStamp`. I believe this is due to an incorrect implementation (according to the help there is definetly a +1 missing on the date field). Sorry, in this case please use the code I provided above (you can also specify negative TDateTime values as starting year, if you want to start with the year 0000).

Comment: Yes but I dont unerstand becouse that exception. Function return a Comp value; if i define MSec as comp variable type, why not agree it? is a bug?

Comment: Hello @chris, i have found the bug in System.SysUtils to line 16434 where report this line:  "if (TimeStamp.Time < 0) or (TimeStamp.Date <= 0) or" the correct should to be: "if (TimeStamp.Time < 0) or (TimeStamp.Date < 0) or". Doing this modify the problem is solved and function return correct value.

Comment: @Marcello: That's not a bug - a `TTimeStamp` must not have a value less than 1 in the date field (see the help article). It's `MSecsToTimeStamp` that produces a wrong result. I reported that to [QC](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=103551). I suggest either using the code provided in my original answer or rewriting `MSecsToTimeStamp` yourself instead.

Comment: Infact, the correct is:   Timestamp.date < 0 and not timestamp.date <= 0. when timestamp.date <= 0 return exception otherwise not. PS: the procedure that raise an exception is: ValidateTimeStamp; it simply check if value date and time of TTimeStamp are greater or egual to 0 in case raise a exception.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand your question.

*If you want to translate a number of days (in some timespan):*

There is nothing exactly like this, for the simple reason that it would not be well-defined, for the reason you give: not every month has the same number of days. Hence, the input *cannot* be only a number of days. For example, what should the result be if you input "35 days"? Should it be "1 month, 4 days" or "1 month, 5 days", "1 month, 6 days", or "1 month, 7 days"? Instead, you need to specify the initial and finial dates.

Now, in `DateUtils`, you have `DaysBetween`, `MonthsBetween`, and `YearsBetween`, but these *are* only approximate.

If you can live with approximate values, it is easy, though: The number of years equals the integer part of the number of days divided by 365.24, the number of months equals the fractional part times 12, and so on.

*If you want to obtain the Nth day of some year:*

```
IncDay(StartOfTheYear(SomeYear), N)
```

Comment: Hello, it true, i supposed that initial date was 0 (year = 0, month 0, day = 0). Datetime is a real value, i saw that setting datetime variable for example to 0.99999999 it turn me 23 hours, 59 minutes, 59 seconds and 999 miliseconds; so i have thinked that setting it 1.0000000 was equeal to 1 days, 0 months, 0 years but to me return 1899 years, 12 months and 30 days that is of course wrong (for mine case). Too if i have understood that it for delphi represent first date available.

Comment: @Marcello: You should consider reading the help article for [`TDateTime`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.TDateTime) ;-)

Comment: Yes @Chris, infact i understood becouse the result was it, reading there.